# Redis set operation options

Tags: redis

Can I store key and value in the following format in Redis? 
※Multiple keys and values are associated with a single global unique key↓.

```
Unique_Key Key_1  some_url_1
           Key_2  some_url_2
           Key_3  some_url_3
           Key_4  some_url_4
             |         |
             |         |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to use *hash* (aka *hash table*) data structure:

```
hset unique_key key_1 some_url_1
hset unique_key key_2 some_url_2
```

Or

```
hmset unique_key key_1 some_url_1 key_2 some_url_2
```

Check [Redis *hash* commands](http://redis.io/commands#hash).